# Cpanel UAPI: Service::create_temp_user

Tags: php, cpanel

Today we are trying to get links to integrated services in cPanel (phpMyAdmin,...) through the API. As we are building a customer interface where customers can do basic actions with their cPanel account (create e-mailaccounts, change DNS records,...)
We would love if our customers don't have to sign in again when redirected to the service.

In order to work the URL should contain a cPanel session ID. After a few hours of searching all API's, we found that the UAPI `Service::create_temp_user` generates the ID we need in our links.

When we call the function it however returns no ID, even if we call it in the API-shell.

Returned:

```
object(stdClass)[52]
    public 'module' => string 'Session' (length=7)
    public 'result' => 
        object(stdClass)[79]
            public 'status' => int 1
            public 'errors' => null
            public 'messages' => null
            public 'metadata' => 
                object(stdClass)[53]
        public 'data' => 
            object(stdClass)[35]
                public 'created' => int 0
    public 'apiversion' => int 3
    public 'func' => string 'create_temp_user' (length=16)
```

As you can see the call 'works correct' as the returned `result->status == 1`. But the `created` value is `0` and no session ID was created/returned.

Anyone that uses this function and knows what we are doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe you should try our friends at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). They might have a bit more experience with this.

Comment: It is still a programming question (cPanel API), If I would ask anything about cPanel at Server Fault they mark it as off-topic. I tried anyway :)

Comment: yes it is quite a legible question for on SO, so I'm not closing it or downvoting it, don't worry ;) It's merely a suggestion as I can imagine someone can help you is a bit bigger there/